# Why didn't my friend receive his Careers invite?

Tags: support, invitation, jobs

I invited a friend to join SO Careers, but he didn't receive his invitation, so I sent a 2nd invite to another one of his addresses, and he didn't get that one either.

He says he's checked his spam folders, etc.. but nothing.

Any ideas?

PS-if you look at my account, it will be obvious who, since I only invited one person twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our server logs show both messages being accepted by the remote mail server, so I'm not sure what went wrong once it got there.

I've forwarded the email via normal Gmail to your friend, and CC'ed you so if he can't receive mail you could copy the URL and get it to him some other way.